# State management approach using react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have been using react for a while and at time I find it to be cumbersome to write action and reducers for simple tasks. The approach i use in such cases is as follows

[image]

I find this approach to be effective and less cumbersome in implementing. Any thoughts and drawbacks of this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't define how you should build your app and doesn't suggest a "default" architecture like some other frameworks (e. g. backbone) do. Also, redux is not a necessary part of react. It is used to prevent state from distributing across multiple components - but local state is not an antipattern and you indeed could/should have some. See [this article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) from a redux co-author for details.

Regarding the architecture you you provided on the pic, well, this looks like classic MVC.

- "Data provider component" = model
- "Smart component" = controller
- "Dumb component" = view

Again, react doesn't define what is wrong and what is right. Your idea looks fine. With proper implementation it could be very clear to comprehend.