# Need guidance on encapsulating logic in a react-based data table

Tags: reactjs, datatable, datagrid, redux, react-redux

I'm attempting to create a reusable react data table component using [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) and need guidance on state management.

I've implemented server-side filtering/sorting/infinite scrolling, and am using the local component state to store the table context (filter, current page, data rows, etc).

simplified example:

```
  class DataTableWithFilter
      render() {
        return ( 
              <React.Fragment>
              <DataTableFilterBar
                   value={this.state.filter}
                   onFilterChange={this._handleFilterChange}
                   onSort={this._handleSort}
                   onScroll={this._handleScroll}
               />
              <VirtualizedDataTable
                  records={this.state.records}
              />                      
              </React.Fragment>
        )
      }
      _handleFilterChange() {
         // build up url from state (path, filter, sort index, page index, etc)
         // fetch new data
         // put new data into state
      }
      _handleSort() {...}
      _handleScroll() {...}
      etc
  }
```

At all costs, **I'm trying to prevent the need to duplicate any of the logic used in the table and keep it totally encapsulated within the table component.** The table will be used dozens of time, and thus I want the table to know how to load its own data and handle sorting/filtering/scrolling, and be used in different contexts.

But this is getting complicated, as different uses of the table require parent and sibling components to be able to tell the table to reload it's data. 
Examples include an 'add new record' button that pops a modal and then needs the table to reload after posting the new record to the server. Or a 'delete record' button that needs the data table to reload after posting the deletion to the server.

I see a few options:

1) Make a monolithic EditableDataTableWithFilter component that contains ALL of the state and filtering/sorting/scrolling/modal/button behavior, and optionally renders certain sub-components like the filtering bar or modals. The downside is having everything in one component, and having a lot of behavior that will be unnecessary when using the component as a simple data table without filtering or context dependent buttons/modals. This seems really bad.

2) Make an EditableDataTable component that renders a child DataTableWithFilter component, and adds the logic necessary for showing and submitting data from modals. I assume doing this would again require the table data to be moved up into the EditableDataTable local state and passed to the DataTableWithFilter as a prop, so that that the table reloads when data changes. OR, I would need to find some way to "tell" the child DataTableWithFilter to reload its data. The latter, using refs or similar seems like a poor approach that once again breaks encapsulation. And I'm not sure how I would use a property as a "reload trigger" either.

3) Use a centralized state provider like redux. I haven't introduced redux into the project yet, but I'm wondering if this is the best solution.

Comment: Please go through : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107940/state-management-approach-using-react .... this is what I do when I want to avoid redux.

Comment: Right. But how would you handle this case:
<Container>
<ModalThatNeedsToReloadTable/>
<SmartTableComponent>
    <DumbTableComponent>
</SmartTableComponent>
</Container>

And wanting <SmartTable> to be used with or without modals (or other components) that can affect it.

Answer (score 0):

Find below the component structure(it's just a pseudo code). ok_cb, cancel_cb are callbacks passed to the ModalThatNeedsToReloadTable component and are called from ModalThatNeedsToReloadTable the component. The callbacks would set the desired data in the state using the setState() method this would re-render the entire Container component. Hope this helps.

```
<Container>
    // in this component you can set the data shared between all
    // the components within the container in the components 'state'

    cancel_cb() {
        // this cb will call the set state
        // method which will re-render the component
    }

    ok_cb() {
        // this cb will call the set state
        // method which will re-render the component
    }


    render()

        if(this.props.showModal)
            <ModalThatNeedsToReloadTable show={this.state.showModal}
                onCancelClick={this.cancel_cb}
                onOKClick={this.ok_cb}/>

        <SmartTableComponent> <DumbTableComponent> </SmartTableComponent>

</Container>
```